# List Item Grid Breaking on Firefox

Tags: css

I'm working on this website that generates a grid based on a list of divs. But the grid is breaking on Firefox and I've been digging for hours but still can't make it work. I've tried changing the width of the item, rearranging margin, padding, display, but none of them seems to work. Please help me. 
This is the URL http://sandulsc.nextmp.net/products/blinds-shades/natural-shades.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the following css property:

```
.product-wrap {
    min-height: 254px;
}
```

to

```
.product-wrap {
    min-height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me how you figured it out, my friend?

Comment: I just open your website as mentioned above in Mozilla Firefox browser. There is a tool (ad-on) - Firebug. By using it, i just inspect the element and their css. Change the min-height property to 300px and it works fine.
Even I have also faced the same problem in one of my project. So I knew the anwser.